# Not all the background images of li elements are displayed

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, background-image, nav

I have a Bootstrap's nav with vertical separators, the separators are actually a background images of the `li's` elements.

Here is the separator's code:

```
.navbar-default li + li {
    background:url('../images/buffer1.png') no-repeat top right;
    background-size: auto 90%;
    background-position:right center;
    display: block;

}
```

and here is live example: http://www.bootply.com/QojGnD6oyU

The problem is that in **Firefox and IE** (all versions) instead of 6 vertical separators only 4 or 3 are displayed.

Why and how can I fix it?

Comment: 4, 3 and 2..in these li, there is separators.

Comment: Yes, but the seperators should be after each li element and not only after some of them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, heres a fix that works, the width has been changed to 1px instead of auto:

```
.navbar-default li + li {
    background:url('http://nave.net23.net/buffer1.png') no-repeat top right;
    background-size: 1px 75%;
    background-position:right center;
    display: block;

}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesn't work for me, can you add a fixed example?

Comment: Thanks, do you know why is that happend in the first place? The width auto and 1px aren't the same?

Comment: Not sure why, seems to be some rounding error or edge-case in the rendering. Personally i would use another approach than images as separators. For example:http://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_gradients.asp

Answer (score 0):

Use this css

```
.navbar .nav > li {
    float: right;
    display: inline-block;
    width: auto;
    text-align: center;
    direction: rtl;
    width: 14.28%;
    font-family: Tahoma, Verdana, Segoe, sans-serif;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-weight: bold;
 }
```

this will work in ie and ff too.

Answer (score 0):

Change this part of your CSS, its occurring due to background-color on .active, .dropdown classes

```
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>li + li {
    background:url('http://nave.net23.net/buffer1.png') no-repeat !important;
    background-size: auto 75%;
    background-position:right center!important;
    display: block;

}
```

if you add !important to image and its position, it will fix it on other browsers as well

Comment: we should not use !important. It will affect the use of those element in other area too.

Comment: Its not recommended widely, but, in case, if you running out of ways, you can ! And you can obviously use custom classes to prevent its affect on other elements !

Comment: means i should check where it is affecting and then have to use custom classes ever where? I'm not saying its wrong but a bad practise..

Comment: I said, we can use a custom class, for this navbar - so, only this specific navbar will get this !important property, and if there are multiple navbar, they won't get affected!